# RESTfull api одновременно поддерживающее JSON & XML

Tags: json, xml, api, rest

Подскажите как правильно организовать веб сервис поддерживающий несколько "форматов ответов"(JSON & XML). Как клиенту дать понять серверу в каком виде он(клиент) хочет видеть ответ?

---

- можно указать на тип ответа в самой строке запроса
- можно передать возвращаемый формат в заголовке
- скорее всего можно еще как-то...

Но как будет "правильнее"?

Comment: сделать какой-то параметр default и если нужен запрос не в стандартном формате - передавать как параметр, например как  &format=xml

Comment: @MaksymPrus мне кажется это моветон

Comment: Ну REST на то и REST, что каждая единица информации однозначно определяется глобальным идентификатором, таким как URL, где URL в свою очередь имеет строго заданный формат. И если у вас один  и тот же URL будет возвращать разный ответ (формат ответа - это тоже ответ), в зависимости от каких-то свои внутренних факторов, то это уже будет что-то другое, но не REST и тем более не RESTfull сервис

Comment: а зачем вам такие сложности? поддержать совместимость со старыми клиентами и параллельно перейти на новый формат?

Comment: @Борис Это все от избытка свободного времени, и желание постичь все и вся. Видел когда то несколько сервисов возвращающих и то и то, но как были реализованы не запомнил, вот и всплыло в голове!)

Comment: В Ruby on Rails такое принято указывать в расширении запрашиваемого "файла", типа GET /users/1.json

Comment: Однако существует ещё HTTP-заголовок Accept, в котором клиент может указать один или несколько ожидаемых типов ответа. Но не знаю, насколько это одобряется RESTом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее оптимально, на мой взгляд лучше всего делать примерно так:

```
http://myserver.domain/api/request.json
http://myserver.domain/api/request.xml
```

То есть задавать ожидаемый формат в виде расширения.

Второй вариант:

> можно передать возвращаемый формат в заголовке

это точно антипаттерн

Comment: Content-Type: application/xml или application/json - вполне обычный способ.

Comment: так обычный способ или антипаттерн для REST?

Answer (score 0):

Данные в наш сервис могут поступать (в общем виде) в трех форматах (для любого из HTTP-методов). Это (1)простой список пар `ключ=значение`, (2)JSON-объект и (3)XML-документ. Возвращаться-же могут JSON или XML. Мы можем проявить волюнтаризм и назначить XML основным форматом ответов нашего сервиса.

Таким образом, в случае запросов (1) и (3)-его типов клиент будет получать XML-ответ. В случае-же запроса (2)-ого типа он получает JSON.

Для реализации такого поведения сервиса нужен дополнительный анализатор входящих данных и два метода для соответсвующих форматов ответа.